# Get-ChildItem after Invoke-Command not working on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

I have a script on PowerShell that invokes a command remotely on few Windows 7 and Windows 10 computers.

The Command that running remotely basically creates few files on a directory inside the C:\ partition and after finishing invoking the command I am using `Get-ChildItem` with `Where-Object` to select a specific file.

Example:

```
$ComputerArray = @("win10-01", "Win10-02", "win7-01", "WIn7-02")

foreach ($comp in $ComputerArray) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {
        cd c:\temp
        New-Item test.txt
    }

    $file = Get-ChildItem \\$comp\C$\temp |
            Where-Object {$_.Name -match "test"}

    if ($file -eq $null) {
        'there is no file such as test'
    } else {
        $file
    }
}
```

On Windows 10 machines, there is a result and it shows me that there is a "test.txt" file, on Windows 7 it shows "There is no file such as test".

Needless to say that all of my machines are running PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Just a footnote: I would use `New-Item` with `-Path` instead of using `cd` before and not giving a full path to the command.

Comment: What does actually fail? The creation of the file, or the verification? Does the target directory even exist on the remote host? Can your user access the administrative shares on all hosts?

Comment: I am using the script with domain admin privilege. what basically happens that on windows 7 the $file variable turns out to be null compared to windows 10 that does find the "test" file

Comment: Can you manually browse to `\\win7-01\c$\temp` and within Windows explorer on your machine create a new file there called `test.txt` without problems?